# Check if word has syllables

Tags: python

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work? I thought 'in' can work this way with `or`.

```
word = str(input("Word please: "))

if ('a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u') in word:
    print("Has syllables")
else:
    print("Doesn't have syllables")
```

Comment: Hint: run `'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u'` in a python REPL and see what it returns.

Comment: `I thought in can work this way with or.` It does not. This doesn't work because no such interaction exists in Python. Whoever told you such a thing exists was misinformed.

Comment: I think you mean vowels and not syllables. AEIOU are vowels. In the word `towel`. O and E are the vowels. "tow" and "el" are the syllables.

Comment: @scr Might depend on your accent. Where I'm from you definitely pronounce it more like "Towl" lol

Comment: Sure, but it makes my point regardless. Syllables and vowels are different and OP is mixing both.